# Knowledge article import with OwnerId

Tags: knowledge, import

I'm trying to specify the OwnerId in my CSV file for my Knowledge article bulk imports, otherwise the user who uploads the bulk import file is assigned as the owner for all articles in the upload sheet, but I keep getting an error like this:

> This value [OwnerId] in the header for column 3 cannot be mapped
> (check both the header and its matching FLS)

I've tried placing the OwnerId field in a different column too but I get the same error pointing to a different column number.

Can someone advise?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a chance that the FLS is the problem, maybe?